# How can you scan from the command line with Windows Defender?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-defender

I'm trying to run a Windows Defender scan from the command line. According to the article I found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg131918.aspx) I should be able to run the following:

```
"C:\program files\windows defender\mpcmdrun.exe" -scan 0
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

"Bad Command line - Command Line - Option should start with '-' or '/' 0"

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? To my understanding this should be working?

Comment: The screenshot on that page and `MpCmdRun /?` clearly state **-Scan [-ScanType]** (see the - before ScanType?)

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: `"C:\program files\windows defender\mpcmdrun.exe" -scan -scantype 2`

Elaborated:

1) Open a **simple** (not elevated) command prompt.
It should not be necessary to open an elevated one.

2) Type/copy--> `"C:\program files\windows defender\mpcmdrun.exe" -scan -scantype 2`

**C:\program files\windows defender\mpcmdrun.exe** should be the deafult location of mpcmdrun.exe

Using only **-scan** parameter will use the default settings of Windows defender/essentials

To be certain that it will be performed a **full system scan**, you need to use the **-scantype 2** parameter, like said in the mpcmdrun help.

3) If you have errors, first try to locate where it is the mpcmdrun.exe file on your machine.

This is usually and easily done with a simple search:

From command prompt: `dir /a /b /s c:\mpcmdrun.exe`

From the run window, shortcut: Windows key + R key (Windows + R), or from Windows vista/7 searchbox (right over the start button, after you have clicked it), or from Windows 8/8.1 charm search, or from Windows 8/8.1 - right-click on the start button - run:

```
cmd /k dir /a /b /s c:\mpcmdrun.exe
```

Extracted from the mpcmdrun help:

```
-Scan [-ScanType #] [-File <path> [-DisableRemediation]]  Scans for malicious software
-Scan [-ScanType value]
        0  Default, according to your configuration
        1  Quick scan
        2  Full system scan
        3  File and directory custom scan

           [-File <path>]
                Indicates the file or directory  to be scanned, only valid for custom scan.
```

Comment: Mind elaborating on your answer and explain why this would work?

Comment: Hi Jerry! Why shouldn't it work? :)   Anyway I've added the mpcmdrun options to the answer.

Comment: Explaining so will actually help future readers understand better, and it also improves the quality of your answer! :)

Comment: Ok thank you Jerry, I have elaborated it a bit... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Type directly from start-run:

> cmd /k c:\progra~1\window~2\MpCmdRun.exe -signatureupdate && c:\progra~1\window~2\MpCmdRun.exe -scan -scantype 2

Output:

> Signature update started . . .
>
> Signature update finished. No updates needed
>
> Scan starting...
>
> Scan finished.

If it should not work, check the real pathnames of "c:\program files" and "c:\program files\windows defender"; type directly from start-run:

> cmd /k dir c:\pro* /x

Output:

> 22/01/2013  22.38              **PROGRA~1**     Program Files
>
> 09/02/2013  21.14              PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)

Type directly from start-run:

> cmd /k dir c:\progra~1\windows* /x

Output:

> 25/11/2012  20.56              **WINDOW~2**     Windows Defender
>
> 25/11/2012  20.56              WIA843~1     Windows Journal
>
> 25/11/2012  20.56              WI6A8C~1     Windows Mail
>
> 13/01/2013  14.23              WI54FB~1     Windows Media Player
>
> 26/07/2012  09.13              WI7A8C~1     Windows Multimedia Platform
>
> 26/07/2012  09.12              WINDOW~3     Windows NT
>
> 25/11/2012  20.56              WINDOW~4     Windows Photo Viewer
>
> 26/07/2012  09.13              WIBFE5~1     Windows Portable Devices

Comment: I had to seperate the commands. Somehow the && did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `0` is being detected as an argument. Remove it and try again (the `0` is the default anyway).

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to use an argument. In my example I specified 0, but say I wanted to run a full system scan (which should be a 2). If I try `"C:\program files\windows defender\mpcmdrun.exe" -scan 2` I get the same error.

Comment: @Zenox try MpCmdRun.exe -Scan -2